# CSS x-repeating background avoid undesirable truncation

Tags: css

I've got a horizontally repeating divider background image that looks like this:

[image]

```css
.divider {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCJ6.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Inevitably though, based on the width of the browser window I can end up with a rendering that looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to ensure that the horizontal repetition breaks only through white space in the background image? That is to say, is there a way to use CSS (and maybe some Javascript) to specify something like, don't repeat a copy of the background image unless you can fit the whole repeating tile in the visible area?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to have spaces between the repeating images, you can use 
**[`background-repeat: space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)**:

```css
.divider {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCJ6.png');
  background-repeat: space no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can scale the image to fit with **[`background-repeat: round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)**:

```css
.divider {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCJ6.png');
  background-repeat: round no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Note that both `space` and `round` apply the repetition both horizontally and vertically by default, so if you only want to apply the repetition horizontally, you can pass `no-repeat` as the second parameter (as seen above).

Comment: This (background-repeat: space no-repeat) _looks_ like exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to be behaving that way in my browser with my html in context even though the CSS is certainly applied similarly. What are "the rules" for this technique to work (regarding width, padding, margins and the like for example)?